# Change input field with css

Tags: css

I have a JSF button with input field:

[image]

```
<h:outputLabel for="rowsPerPage" value="Rows per page" />
<h:inputText id="rowsPerPage" value="#{AccountsController.rowsPerPage}" size="3" maxlength="3" style="border: 1px solid #006; height: 24px; border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;" />
<h:commandButton styleClass="bimage" value="Set" action="#{AccountsController.pageFirst}" >
    <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
</h:commandButton>&nbsp;
<h:message for="rowsPerPage" errorStyle="color: red;" />
```

As you can see the input field is below the "set" button. How can I make the button and the input field on one line with css. And also how I can make the input field look like the button?

EDIT: This is the html code:

```
<input id="form:rowsPerPage" type="text" name="form:rowsPerPage" value="10" maxlength="3" size="3" style="border: 1px solid #006; height: 24px; border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;" />
```

Comment: If your question relates specifically to css/html, please post the rendered html from the browser.  If it relates to the JSF code, please add the JSF tag to your question.

Comment: Try adding a 1px border to commandButton as well

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `margin-top: 1px` to your button.